# facebook application php post to friends wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have a script that succesfully posts to my friend wall link and message, but when i turn on loop like this:

```
for ($i = $from; $i <= $to; $i++) {
        $sendTo = $userid[$i];

        echo '<p>sending user '.$i.'</p>';

        if($result = $facebook->api("/$sendTo/feed/",'post', $attachment))                        

                    {
            echo '<p>sended user '.$i.'</p>';
        } else {
            echo 'Oops something went wrong';
        }}
```

it only posts 4 or 5 messages and then break. I suppos the problem is at facebook does not allowing many message to send in short time. How can i make some timeout function or something to post at least 100 messages? When i post only 5 messages i manage to post 100 messages 5 by 5, but i need to post 100 by 100. Can you help me please?

Thank you for your time and best regards

Answer (score 1):

Posting on multiple user's walls like this is discouraged by Facebook. If you want to send multiple users a message, they recommend you use the [requests dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/).

To delay sending requests, you could add a `sleep(300)` command after every 5 posts to give a 5 minute delay between postings. You'll have problems with script timeouts. Better would be to have your script [create a cron job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765454/how-to-set-up-a-cron-job-via-php-not-cpanel) that posts 5 items at a time, and only runs every 5 minutes.

With either of these methods, you are spamming your users and you run a risk of your app getting disabled. See this [Facebook Developers blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/516/) for more info.

Comment: plus, the functionality is scheduled for complete removal in February

Comment: @Igy: I've seen several of these questions recently, and can't find a definitive statement on the developer site that this is true. In fact, it's amazing to me that there is _nothing_ [I can find on the developer site](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adevelopers.facebook.com+"sharer.php") that even references `sharer.php`, especially with all the tutorials still floating around.

Comment: I meant the removal of the ability to post to a friends' feed connection (announced [here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/10/10/growing-quality-apps-with-open-graph/)) - sharer.php is also deprecated and the docs now redirect to the feed dialog, though the docs may come back depending on if/when we plan to totally remove the old sharer endpoint

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I missed the fact that posting via the api had also been deprecated.