# SendGrid API | retrieve List count daily stats for a given date range

Tags: php, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am trying to find a way to **retrieve daily list count statistics** for New Marketing Campaigns on the SendGrid API. The [normal API endpoint for getting the current momentary amount of List contact amount](https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/lists/get-list-contact-count), will not take date range as an input.

What is the proper approach for this? Is there an endpoint?

Potential solutions can of course include a [cron job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php), but that will not gather stats from **prior dates**.

Answer (score 0):

After some support messages and digging I can conclude that the **SendGrid API can not retrieve historical data on the total amount of contacts in a list**. The solution will be to use the endpoint [GET /marketing/lists/{id}/contacts/count](https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/lists/get-list-contact-count) together with a script through a cron job. Ways of setting up a cron job:

- use a cron service like [Online Cron Jobs](http://www.onlinecronjobs.com/), [EasyCron](https://www.easycron.com) or [cron-job.org](https://cron-job.org/en/) to set up a script to run periodically.
- set up a [cron job on a web server](https://sitebeginner.com/build/cronjob/).
- set up a [cron job without cpanel access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765454/how-to-set-up-a-cron-job-via-php-not-cpanel) (or equivalent)

Many **web hosting solutions** offer cron jobs or recurring tasks included with the packaged tools in **cpanel** or others alike.