# How to assign cron jobs through php

Tags: php, cron

Is it possible to schedule some tasks in php to run automatically on the server at a certain time of the day? . I heard abt cron jobs. is there any way to set it via php code

Comment: BTW, http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+set+cron

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cron jobs using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264756/cron-jobs-using-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/system lets you to run any command-line utility.

As for the certain command to set a cron job you have either to google a little or ask on serverfault.